# Hex to JPG conversion in C++

Tags: c++, hex, jpeg, binaryfiles

I am writing a C++ program where I Need to convert some string output which is basically in HEX format. This output string starts with FFD8 and Ends with FFD9 which is basically a JPEG Image.

Now, I want to get the JPEG file from that string output  but I don't want to save that string output in a text file and open it in ios::binary mode and then covert it to a JPEG file.

```
std::string output; //which is FFD8..........FFD9

//******some code*******???

ofstream imageFile;
imageFile.open('Image.jpg');
imageFile<< output;
```

How I can do that without saving my string output in a file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about the format of the string. Is it just a jpeg file in text?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you have a string representing hex, and you want to convert that to the byte equivalent.

```
byte hexCharToByte(const char h){
    if(isdigit(h))
        return h - '0';
    else
        return toupper(h) - 'A' + 10;
}
```

This is some code I wrote a while back in C that takes a char and converts it to a byte. You can adapt it however you need.

How it works:

- Hex values are represented by 0-15
- If you receive a char that is a number, e.g. '0', you subtract '0'. The result is 0
- If you receive a letter, say 'a', make sure it's uppercase. 'A' - 'A' is 0. The hex value of 'A' is 10, so we must add 10 to get its hex value.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string output; //which is FFD8..........FFD9

int main()
{
    std::ofstream thum("name.jpg", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::out);

    char buf[3];
    buf[2] = 0;

    std::stringstream in(output);
    in.flags(std::ios_base::hex);
    while (in)
    {
        in >> buf[0] >> buf[1];
        long val = strtol(buf, nullptr, 16);
        thum << static_cast<unsigned char>(val & 0xFF);
    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).